# How to add analytics label when we send data message via legacy app server protocols

Tags: python, android, firebase, push-notification

We are using legacy app server protocols to send Firebase data message, for several years.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-using-the-legacy-app-server-protocols

```
#
# headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'key={}'.format(constants.FCM_AUTHORIZATION_KEY)}
#
# request_data = {'to' : valid_enabled_token, 'data' : {'sync': sync, 'sync_device_count': sync_device_count}}
#
r = requests.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', headers=headers, json=request_data)
```

However, recently, we cannot see any delivery report in Firebase console.

We notice we need to add **analytics label** according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery

> Important: An analytics label is required to display all types of
>   statistics for data messages.

However, it isn't clear on how to add **analytics label** via legacy method.

Can anyone provide a simple example on how to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already described:

> You can add a label to any message sent via the HTTP v1 API by setting
>   the fcmOptions.analyticsLabel field in the message object.

E.g.:

```
  fcm_options: {
    analytics_label: "test_label"
  }
```

In your case you would have to add the `analytics_label` to `fcm_options` within your `request_data`, e.g.:

```js
const headers = {
  "content-type": "application/json",
  Authorization: "key={}".format(constants.FCM_AUTHORIZATION_KEY)
};

const request_data = {
  to: valid_enabled_token,
  data: { sync: sync, sync_device_count: sync_device_count },
  fcm_options: {
    analytics_label: "test_label"
  }
};

const r = requests.post(
  "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send",
  (headers = headers),
  (json = request_data)
);
```

Alternatively you can use the platform-specific `AndroidFcmOptions` (FCM SDK for Android) or `ApnsFcmOptions` (FCM SDK for iOS) fields to add the `analytics_label` as described above.

**Update**: However it seems that the Legacy HTTP Server Protocol does not (yet) support the analytics_label and / or fcm_options.

> With the HTTP v1 API, the analytics label can be set when sending the
>   message, in order to mark the message for analytics purposes

Unfortunately the visualization data is only available for messages with notification payload or labeled data messages:

> This data is available for all messages with a notification payload
>   and all labeled data messages. To learn more about labels, see Adding
>   analytics labels to messages.

See

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery#adding_analytics_labels_to_messages
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages#FcmOptions

Comment: I get the following input and output - https://gist.github.com/yccheok/ad10bb7cae6c1ab7ec80b8cd38b90271 However, I still see 0 send record in Firebase Cloud Messaging console - https://i.imgur.com/1QptyDy.png Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: The issue of not being able to see any delivery report seems unrelated to the missing analytics_label it seems. Do you receive a 200 status code? Are messages delivered correctly? Did you apply some filter?

Comment: But, as in documentation, it mentions "Important: An analytics label is required to display all types of statistics for data messages."

Comment: I updated my original answer. It seems the analytics label is not set from the legacy protocol. Also only messages with labeled data or notifications are visualized. The only option seems to be to migrate to the HTTP API v1.

Comment: Thanks. I try to do a quick implementation of HTTP API v1. However, I'm facing the following issue - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60164581/72437 Do you mind to provide some valuable input? Thanks.

Comment: Also be careful about this: "Max length is 50 characters. You can specify up to 100 unique labels per day; messages with labels added beyond that limit are not reported". Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery